# Show Data Based On Query Params in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, query-string

Can i filter out the data using query params in Angular? This.rows is an array.
I'll only show this.rows that has the query params of "Pending".  How will i able filter out this using queryParams. Here's my code below.

```
// this.rows is an array



this.activeRouter.queryParams
.filter(params => params.q)
.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params);
  if(this.rows.status === params.q){
    return this.rows;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get query params like this using ActivatedRoute and then store it in one variable and use filter to get pending entries in rows.

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {OnInit, Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
 queryParamsStatus ='';

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe to router event
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.queryParamsStatus= params['status'];
        console.log(queryParamsStatus );

      });
    let tempRows = this.rows.filter(s => s.staus === this.queryParamsStatus);
  }

}
```